# How does WooCommerce grouped product child orderby works in WC 3.0+?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

In Wordpress Woocommerce I have created a grouped product, with lots of sub products (children) in it. I tried searching everywhere, but I can not find a working solution how to orderby them by either SKU or product name. It seems that it's orderby is generated by "Menu Order" only. Although as I have 30+ sub products in these multiple grouped products, it would be extremely time wasting to order them by Menu Order value.

I tried the following code, but it seems that it worked in WC 2.5, but not 3.0+ .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 'so_22661392_grouped_children_args' );

function so_22661392_grouped_children_args( $args ){

$args['meta_key'] = 'sku';
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
$args['order'] = 'ASC'; 
return $args;

}
```

I also searched Google for explanations but could not find any. I tried to clear transients, this doesn't work as well:

```
  WooCommerce>System Status>Tools>Clear Transients
```

The grouped product can be seen [here](https://plastmet.ee/uus/toode/umartoru-kork-zzo-pealekaiv/) . The html table should match the children below, but it does not. SKU for children is "563/9005", "567/9005" etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where you want see them ordered? Admin panel or web page?

Comment: web page. I don't care about admin panel :)

Comment: Anyone? Still need help, thanks.